# Python Regex findall: get exact string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, findall

I am trying to get the required string using python re.findall. The string is as below.

```
abcd|123|ABCD|112233|
abcd|234|ABCD|112233|
abcd.abc|123|ABCD|112233|
efgh|234|EFGH|445566|
efgh|4567|EFGH|445566|
efgh.abc|6789|EFGH|445566|
efgh.abc|4567|EFGH|445566|
xyz|567|XYZ|557799|
xyz.abc|567|XYZ|557799|
```

I need all the lines which starts with "efgh" so I am using re.findall('efgh.*', data), but I am getting like below.. I just need first two lines (efgh ones, not with efgh.abc). I am able to get the same using re.search('efhg(.*)', data).group but getting only first line and missing the second line. Kindly help how I can achieve this.

```
efgh|234|EFGH|445566|             <-  These two rows
efgh|4567|EFGH|445566|            <-
efgh.abc|6789|EFGH|445566|
efgh.abc|4567|EFGH|445566|
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use:

```
^efgh\b(?!\.).*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `efgh\b` Match the "word" `efgh`
- `(?!\.)` Negative lookahead, assert not a literal dot to the right
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cPTZIf/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/S8jJVX)

```
import re

pattern = r"^efgh\b(?!\.).*"

s = ("abcd|123|ABCD|112233|\n"
    "abcd|234|ABCD|112233|\n"
    "abcd.abc|123|ABCD|112233|\n"
    "efgh|234|EFGH|445566|\n"
    "efgh|4567|EFGH|445566|\n"
    "efgh.abc|6789|EFGH|445566|\n"
    "efgh.abc|4567|EFGH|445566|\n"
    "xyz|567|XYZ|557799|\n"
    "xyz.abc|567|XYZ|557799|")

print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M))
```

Output

```
['efgh|234|EFGH|445566|', 'efgh|4567|EFGH|445566|']
```

---

Or if there is always a pipe following:

```
^efgh\|.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DhzAP2/1)

Note that `re.findall` returns the value of a capture group if that is present. If you want the full match, you can omit the capture groups.

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for the quick help.. Yes the pipe always follows and ^efgh\|.* giving exactly what i required.. Appreciate your quick help..